# Data driven Spock test

Tags: spock, data-driven-tests

I am doing some very basic Spock refresher drills and I am trying to do a data driven test.  Here is the spec:

```groovy
package drills

import drills.StringReverse
import spock.lang.Specification

import org.junit.Test

class TestSpockReverseString extends Specification {

    @Test
    def "test"(String inString, String expectedString){

        given:

        StringReverse systemUnderTest = new StringReverse();

        when:
        String actualString = systemUnderTest.reverseString(inString);

        then:
        expectedString.equals(actualString)

        where:
        inString    | expectedString
        null        | null
        ""          | ""
        "abc"       | "cba"
        "aaa"       | "aaa"
        "abcd"      | "dcba"
        "asa"       | "asa"
    }
}
```

Every time I run it I get this error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT3Oy.png)

I have gone through the Spock doc and read other examples online, and it looks like I am setting up the spec correctly.  I am running Eclipse IDE for EE Java.  Version 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Some setting I need to update to get Groovy and Spock to work together properly?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I tried using one of the specs from here:

https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/DataDrivenSpec.groovy

Namely this one:

```groovy
def "minimum of #a and #b is #c"() {
  expect:
  Math.min(a, b) == c

  where:
  a | b || c
  3 | 7 || 3
  5 | 4 || 4
  9 | 9 || 9
}
```

Same issues as above.  I am thinking there is something wrong with my Eclipse setup.  I've looked at the groovy compiler, test runners and do not know where else to look.   Again, any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing `def "test"(String inString, String expectedString){` to `def "test"(){` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both.  When I do it with no args it underlines inString and expectedString in the method like they can not be found and I get the same initialization error.

Comment: Definitely follow Michal's advise, `def "test()"`. I think the new error you got pertains to a different error. Maybe you can add that to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get rid of the JUnit `@Test` annotation in Spock tests, then it will work with or without feature method parameters. Here is a less verbose and more "spockish" version of your specification:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q63959033

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class TestSpockReverseString extends Specification {
  @Unroll
  def "reversing '#inString' yields '#expectedString'"() {
    expect:
    expectedString == new StringReverse().reverseString(inString)

    where:
    inString | expectedString
    null     | null
    ""       | ""
    "abc"    | "cba"
    "aaa"    | "aaa"
    "abcd"   | "dcba"
    "asa"    | "asa"
  }

  static class StringReverse {
    String reverseString(String string) {
      string?.reverse()
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, `@Unroll` will be the default in Spock 2.0, you only need it in 1.x versions.

Comment: .When I get rid of the Test annotation, eclipse tells me no JUnits found.  I also can run other groovy specs with Test annotation and no where clause.  It just crashes when I have a where clause

Comment: Then your Eclipse instance is not configured properly for Spock tests (or maybe also for Groovy) and you are having an Eclipse problem. I just told you how to fix your Spock test because something was wrong with it. I use IntelliJ IDEA, so I cannot help you with the Eclipse bit, but I quickly googled [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spock-plugin) for you. Please also don't forget Groovy-Eclipse. I also recommend to use Maven or Gradle in order to build your project and then just import the build into Eclipse, Maven/Gradle being the leading system.

Comment: As the actual Spock question is answered, would you please accept and upvote it? Feel free to create a new question concerning Groovy and Spock support in Eclipse specifically, describing your Eclipse configuration and your problems. Thank you.